# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column when trying to merge two dataframes

Tags: dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes using this code: merge(df_feature, df_taxonomy, by = "Feature_ID")
I keep getting the error: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column and I don't know why,

I have checked both dataframes and while one initially contained an extra line which was mistaken for the column name, I have since fixed this problem and when I check both using the View command both dataframes do have the same column name, Feature_ID. I can't say with certainty that the data underneath Feature_ID is the same in both df's, it's possible they're in a different order but they might also just be the same. I don't know if that could cause trouble? I'm quite inexperienced in R so I don't really know in what direction to even search.

Comment: What language is this code in, and what packages/modules are you using? Could you show an MWE for the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.